# Status of Beal, Granville, Tijdeman-Zagier Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

The Beal, Granville, Tijdeman-Zagier Conjecture, i.e.

If $A^x+B^y=C^z$ , where $A, B, C, x, y,z$ are positive integers and $x,
y$ and $z$ are all greater than $2$, then $A, B$ and $C$ must have a common prime
factor.

... and its associated [$1,000,000 prize](http://ns3.ams.org/bealprize.html) for proof or disproof seems to have gone largely unnoticed in the mathematics community. Please answer with (A) references to past or ongoing research or (B) references to equivalent forms of this conjecture known prior to Andrew Beal posing it in 1993.

Comment: I guess that you should look at the following article http://www.ams.org/notices/199711/beal.pdf
It mentions some related conjectures made prior to Beal.

Comment: I think you should edit this. Right now the only actual question in your post is about a controversial subject.

Comment: In this interesting overview paper, http://www.thehcmr.org/issue1_1/elkies.pdf, the conjecture is referred to as the Tijdeman-Zagier conjecture. There is no explicit reference, though.

Comment: Nils Bruin covers the conjecture briefly in Chabauty methods and covering techniques applied to generalised Fermat equations, PhD-thesis, University of Leiden, 1999. See also: springerlink.com/content/a177k83512kp6301.

Comment: This question remains entirely unanswered.

Comment: Perhaps it is time to close the question.

Comment: Well, the question was just answered and accepted. Perhaps the threat of imminent closure was the needed catalyst...

Comment: Richard Guy's book *[Unsolved Problems in Number Theory][1]*, pages 113-116, gives a very good account of the history of the conjecture.

  [1]: http://books.google.com/books?id=1AP2CEGxTkgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=unsolved+problems+in+number+theory&source=bl&ots=Tiqud1BOpF&sig=84vZyZ4bbr2OsQDltXLff0YRCIs&hl=en&ei=z6H6TN-QBY-osAP08Oj2DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false


Comment: I just reverted Halfdan Faber's change of the title. I think anyone looking for the conjecture with only Beal's name attached to it will not be confused by finding the extra names. Whereas omitting those names is tacitly taking Beal's side of the story, and I am not sure we should do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sci.math discussions linked to above suggest that Andrew Granville suggested the problem in 1992 and that it was discussed as early as 1985.

I have in my notes:

T-Z predates Beal; see Frits Beukers, "The Diophantine equation $Ax^p+By^q=Cz^r$", *Duke Math. J.* **91**:1 (1998), pp. 61-88.

This kind of informal documentation may be the best available, unfortunately.

*Edit to expand on a comment:*

On sci.math, Gerry Myerson [wrote on Aug 22 2000](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=255524):

> Since Andrew Granville's contribution to the Western Number Theory 
>   problem list has come up in this discussion, I want to put it on record 
>   here.
>   The December 1992 Western Number Theory meeting was held in Corvallis. 
>   The problem list was edited by Richard Guy and is dated 9 June 93. 
>   The relevant part of Problem 92:12 reads as follows.
>
> ---
>
> 92:12 (Andrew Granville) Find examples of
>
> x^p + y^q = z^r with 1/p + 1/q + 1/r < 1 
>   other than 2^3 +1^7 = 3^2 and 7^3 + 13^2 = 2^9. [Blair Kelly III gave 
>   2^5 + 7^2 = 3^4 and Reese Scott 17^3 + 2^7 = 71^2.]
>
> ---
>
> In Guy's write-up of the 1993 problems, dated 3 March 94, there is a 
>   comment about 92:12, wherein Granville agrees with the suggestion that 
>   it was intended that x, y and z be relatively prime, and gives 
>   3^5 + 11^4 = 122^2 as another example. Peter Montgomery gave 5 larger 
>   examples found by Beukers & Zagier.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. See: http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~roblot/ihp/Fermatlectures.pdf (later version, it appears). It would be nice to see some informal documentation predating 1993, in the absence of any concise reference.

Comment: In one of those sci.math discussions, I wrote, "The December 1992 Western Number Theory meeting was held in Corvallis. 
The problem list was edited by Richard Guy and is dated 9 June 93. 
The relevant part of Problem 92:12 reads as follows. 
92:12 (Andrew Granville) Find examples of 
    $x^p + y^q = z^r$ with $1/p + 1/q + 1/r \lt 1$ 
other than $2^3 +1^7 = 3^2$ and $7^3 + 13^2 = 2^9$." I consider that to be a concise reference to formal documentation preceding 1993. 

Comment: The second part of this question was also answered indirectly. There appears to have been very little, if any, work related to the BGTZ Conjecture in recent years.

Answer (score 11):

At present there is no real strategy for the general problem.  But progress on individual cases, or families of cases, keeps moving along.  For instance, Poonen, Schaeffer, and Stoll [handled the case x^2 + y^3 + z^7](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0508/0508174v1.pdf) in 2005; last year, Mike Bennett, Nathan Ng and I [finished off the case x^2 + y^4 = x^p](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~ellenber/BeElNgdraftFINAL.pdf) and [David Brown did x^2 + y^3 + z^10](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2932).

Answer (score 8):

There was a great deal of discussion in the sci.math newsgroup about a decade
ago. See the threads
[Beal's Conjecture](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/sci.math/browse_thread/thread/31cd9a6140a743f5/f3d6fc0644a98481?hl=en&q=sci.math+beal%2527s+conjecture&lnk=ol&) and [Against the term "Beal Conjecture"](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/sci.math/browse_thread/thread/d8d2ad7d61a796e3/1755be7ffc2bfd5a?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=sci.math+beal%2527s+conjecture#1755be7ffc2bfd5a).
As with most sci.math discussions, they generated more heat than light.

Comment: "As with most sci.math discussions, they generated more heat than light."

You can say that again.  Wow... let's hope MO steers clear of that sort of discussions.


Comment: I've been very impressed with the MO moderator's ability to prevent cranks from taking over the site.  When I first heard about it, I expected that it would quickly degenerate into something akin to sci.math...

Comment: sci.math.research never degenerated into that sort of thing, but that's because it's moderated. There's the advantage of moderation, but the disadvantage is that is slows the site down (e.g. I'm supposed to be the moderator today, but I've just been asleep for 8 hours). At the time of setting sci.math.research up there wasn't really the machinery available to have the whole community moderating. That's the breakthrough this site offers.