# Need help publishing a mathematical proof?

Tags: nt.number-theory, conjectures

Im not a mathematician with profession, but I know a group working on a [Beal's Conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28764/status-of-beal-granville-tijdeman-zagier-conjecture) for years. They think that they have found a proof but the problem is that they don't know how to publish because he is born mathematician not a professor or a mathematician student. We are from Macedonia in Southeastern Europe and we couldn't find someone who can prepare it for publishing. Can someone give me any useful information where I can contact someone or any institution who can help us in this direction?

Comment: The basic advice is too write it, check details and formulation and then put in on ArXiv. You can then send the link to people working in the subject to have more advices, before submitting to a journal.

Comment: @Jérémy, you can't put something on ArXiv unless someone vouches for you, right? I'm guessing these people don't know anyone who can do that for them.

Comment: The problem is that he is born mathematician, he has graduated in chemistry but all his life working in mathematical problems. So he dont know how to publish it because the biggest problem is that he doesnt know english or use a computer.

Comment: Also posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716675/need-help-publishing-a-mathematical-proof

Comment: @Zemri, well, this is a big problem. It will very difficult to find someone mathematically expert who has the time to translate a long proof from Macedonian to English and also to typeset it.

Comment: Perhaps you should try asking people working at the math department of your local university?

Comment: In Macedonia there are two Universities Kirili and Metodij and State University of Tetova who have Mathematics faculty but the big question is why I have written and asking for help is that no one is helping because he is out of the academic scene and you cant find anyone working on big mathematical problems like this.

Comment: You don't need anyone working on big problems! If the proof is correct, you can explain it to a good student in one of these universities.

Comment: First it should be translated from Macedonian to English.  A mathematics student at a Macedonian university is a likely candidate to do this.  (For a fee, of course.)

Answer (score 14):

You should start by reading this page of advice by Henry Cohn:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cohn/Thoughts/advice.html

As it says there (among many other useful things), you should prepare a paper using LaTeX.  It takes some time and effort to learn LaTeX, but it is much easier to learn LaTeX than to prove a valuable theorem.  In practice, academic mathematicians will use this as an informal test: if you have taken the time to use the standard tools, they will be more willing to take you seriously.

Comment: Very nice page. It contains a lot of interesting advices.

Comment: The link in the post no longer works - it is now located here: https://cohn.mit.edu/advice ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230131190037/https://cohn.mit.edu/advice)).